# IE 8 custom checkbox image

Tags: image, checkbox, internet-explorer-8

I'm using a custom image for checkboxes and I'm seeing some strange behavior in IE 8. In order to use the custom image I'm using a label with a background-image for checked, checked-focus, unchecked, unchecked-focus, and hiding the checkbox. The issue is that the hidden checkbox is causing IE 8 to incorrectly display the state of the label, i.e., when the label is initially clicked the state of the label is updated correctly, however, upon subsequent click events the label will only update correctly if clicked twice. Any suggestions?

```
'label[for="remember_me"] mousedown' : function(el, ev){
    var rememberMe = $('#remember_me');
    rememberMe.attr('checked', !rememberMe.attr('checked'));
    $(el).attr('checked', !rememberMe.attr('checked'));
},

'label[for="remember_me"] mouseup' : function(el, ev){
    var rememberMe = $('#remember_me');
    rememberMe.attr('checked', !rememberMe.attr('checked'));
    $(el).attr('checked', !rememberMe.attr('checked'));

input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

#remember_elements > label {
background: url("../../images/checkmark-unchecked-normal.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
float: left;
margin-right: 10px;
}
#remember_elements > label:hover {
background: url("../../images/checkmark-unchecked-focus.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#remember_elements > label[checked="checked"] {
background: url("../../images/test/checkmark-checked-normal-renault.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
#remember_elements > label[checked="checked"]:hover {
background: url("../../images/test/checkmark-checked-focus-renault.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

checked is a bolean attribute.
eg.
both  and  are valid.... for interoperability with xhtml the full checked="checked" is required.... (xhtml conformance checking requires all attributes to be quoted strings).... possibly in IE8 though the full checked="checked" is required.

try #elid[checked] i/o #elid[checked="checked"]

A word of warning..... input elements also accept keyboard events. The space bar can also be used to toggle the checked attribute of an input[type=checkbox]

jquery.mobile has the framework for switch style checkbox overlays.